# Form submit only submits on the 2nd click, need callback in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Clicking on Submit invokes my `onSubmit` function where it does 2 things:

1. setState for `formValidity` (bool)
2. submits the form

The issue is that it fails on first click and only submits on the second time.
I understand this is coming from eval that submits even though it doesn't yet have the states set and fails on first run.

I would like onSubmit to preform setStates and only then preform eval for sending the mail in one click.

**Please note:** I've tried splitting the function and that had the same result.

I'm assuming a callback would be in place here yet I don't know how to apply this correctly with ES6.

### rendered element:

`<button onClick={(event) => this.onSubmit(event)}>Submit</button>`

### onSubmit function:

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!validator.isEmail(this.state.email)) {
        this.setState({
            errorType: this.state.formErrors["email"],
            formValidity: false
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            formValidity: true
        })
    }
    if (!validator.isAlpha(this.state.fName) || !validator.isAlpha(this.state.lName)) {
        this.setState({
            errorType: this.state.formErrors["name"],
            formValidity: false
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            formValidity: true
        })
    }
    if (this.state.formValidity === true) {
        console.log('mail sent!');

    } else {
        console.log('One of the inputs is erroneous');

    }

}
```

Just to iterate to make sure I explained this well, I would like `if (this.state.formValidity === true)` to run **only after ** all the other conditionals eval'd and stay in the same function scope.

thanks,
Bud

Answer (score 2):

Remove the event handler from the button and add it to your form element: 
`<form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>` and bind `this.handleOnSubmit` in the constructor.

Regarding your checkups, I would advise you to perform your check for each of the input fields upon their change event and update the state accordingly. For example:

```
<input name="email" onChange={this.validateEmail}>
```

And this (binded) function can perform your check for the `email` field, if it’s valid and if the `name` field is valid, simply update the `this.formValidity` state to true.

Then, in your `handleOnSubmit` function, remove everything except for your form validation checkup.

**EDIT:** 
Change all your inputs' `onChange` handlers to contain a reference to a specific function that will perform a validation for certain input field (and update the corresponding field's value - if you are already using that). For example (referring to the input field from before):

```
validateEmail() {
   // Update input's state value
   // Perform validation for email input and update corresponding state
}
```

Now the thing is, I would advise you to create additional state properties (one for each input field) to track individual field's validity state, like so:

```
this.state = {
  ...,
  fNameValid: false,
  lNameValid: false,
  emailValid: false,
  telValid: false,
}
```

Now your specific validation functions will only update the state that is concerned with the specific field, not the whole form (and your errorType):

```
validateEmail() {
   // Update input's state value

   if (!validator.isEmail(this.state.email)) {
      this.setState({
        emailValid: false,
        errorType: this.state.formErrors["email"],
      })
   } else {
      this.setState({
        emailValid: true
      })
   }
}
```

Finally, have your `onSubmit` event handler perform the checkup for all fields:

```
handleOnSubmit() {
   let isFormValid = this.state.fNameValid
                  && this.state.lNameValid
                  && this.state.emailValid
                  && this.state.telValid;

   if (isFormValid) {
     console.log('mail sent!');
   } else {
     console.log('One of the inputs is erroneous');
   }
}
```

State's `formValidity` property becomes redundant in the end.

Comment: This is my formError child component: https://pastebin.com/33jg6fhz and this is ComponentForm (holding formError comp.): https://pastebin.com/60GUyKk4
And its state in ComponentForm : 
https://pastebin.com/Giem8jkm
That logic would make more sense to separate them, can you edit your answer to reflect this? Also please let me know if I missed any info.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to test `formValidity`'s value from state? If not, `if (this.state.formValidity === true)` is overkill, and you can restructure your logic so that the async nature of `setState` is easier to account for — something like:

```
onSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault()

  let formValidity = true
  let errorType = undefined

  if (!validator.isEmail(this.state.email)) {
    formValidity = false
    errorType = this.state.formErrors.email
  } else if (!validator.isAlpha(this.state.fName) || !validator.isAlpha(this.state.lName)) {
    formValidity = false
    errorType = this.state.formErrors.name
  }

  if (!formValidity) {
    this.setState({
      formValidity,
      errorType
    }, () => console.log('Form is invalid'))
  } else {
    this.setState({
      formValidity,
      errorType
    }, () => console.log('Form is valid'))
  }
}
```

You'll also see I take advantage of `setState`'s callback, which can be safely assumed to run only after the state has been set.

Comment: hi, I get form invalid in any state, even when correct

Comment: I like this design though, let me know if you can fix it to work

Comment: I need some sleep... it's edited now :--). And if you have the time, definitely look into @Kox's advice below about validating your form inputs onChange; that's the better long-term solution.

Comment: thanks, Kox's advice is right also. too bad stackoverflow doesn't allow multiple correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

setState is an async function,you could add the mail sent code or any such code dependent on formValidity=true as a callback to the setState function so there should be no need of the last if-else block.Always avoid the last if-else block since setState runs in an async manner.

```
this.setState({
        formValidity: true
    },function(){
        console.log("mail sent");
         //or any other code dependent on formValidity set to true.
    });
```